# Autoscroll down angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, autoscroll

Hi I'm creating a chat app with angularjs that autoscrolls down when a user messages another user.  I'm not sure how to implement this as my chat window is a fixed ul element.  I'm thinking I will need to implement a directive to do this (inboxmsg-scroll on the ul element)

Any help? thanks.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="chatting-window" inboxmsg-scroll>
    <li data-ng-repeat="messageinfo in messages">
        <div class="message-date">
            {{messageinfo[0]}}
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular directive to scroll to a given item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790854/angular-directive-to-scroll-to-a-given-item)

Comment: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInclude

Comment: @HackedByChinese I want to scroll the element not the entire window (which was the question u linked)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**angularjs-scroll-glue**

> An AngularJs directive that automatically scrolls to the bottom of an
>   element on changes in it's scope.

Link: https://github.com/Luegg/angularjs-scroll-glue