# How to automatically scroll down to bottom of div as the new contents are added in the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

```
<div class="container">
    <label ng-repaet"x in items">{{x}}</label>
</div>
```

I want the scroll bar of the container div to go at the bottom automatically as the container overflows, and label items are added into it.

The css class for the div container is:

```
.container{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-wrap:break-word;
    height:300px;
}
```

And also i have styled my scroll bar as follows:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width:6px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    border-radius: 0px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790854/angular-directive-to-scroll-to-a-given-item try this

Comment: It didn't work for me @Jimbrooism

Comment: I already checked that, it didn't work. @AlexLogan

Answer (score 0):

You can add `$scope.$watch` in your directive's link function like so:

```
function dynamicContainer() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        template: '<div class="container container-dynamic"><div ng-repeat="item in data track by $index">{{item}}</div></div>',
        scope: {
            data: '=data'
        },
        replace: true,
        link: ($scope, $el, $attrs) => {
            $scope.$watch(() => {
                return $el[0].childNodes.length;
            }, (newValue, oldValue) => {
                $el.animate({
                    scrollTop: $el[0].scrollHeight
                });

                if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                    $el.animate({
                        scrollTop: $el[0].scrollHeight
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Here's a [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPYvZj?editors=1111) for you.